# Hide API Resource Field / Belongs To Many Through Deep Relationship Problem

Tags: laravel, resources, relationship

It seems as if the tutorial right here doesn't work as intended https://hackernoon.com/hiding-api-fields-dynamically-laravel-5-5-82744f1dd15a

I am aware of how to load relationships only if necessary by making use of "whenLoaded", but for simple field parameters that do not involve a relationship, I am unable to dynamically load these fields.

Below is a snippet of Agency.php

```
'expected_num_of_b_positive_donors' => $this->getExpectedNumOfDonors("B+"),
'elligible_to_schedule_mbd' => $this->
'donors' => $this->getDonors(),
 'contact_persons' => $this->getContactPersons(),
'last_mbd' => $this->getLastMBD(),
'average_number_of_donors_per_day' => $this->getAverageNumberofDonorsPerDay()
```

This would all have been extremely easy, if Laravel came out of the box with a Belongs To Many Through Deep Relationship, as I could have easily used:

```
'donors' => $this->whenLoaded("donors")
```

instead of:

```
'donors' => $this->getDonors(),
```

For context, here is a snippet of my getDonors()

```
   $donors = [];
               // MBD -> Schedule -> Donation List -> Donor
               foreach($this->mbds as $mbd){
                    foreach($mbd->mbd_schedules as $schedule){
                         foreach($schedule->donation_list as $donation_list){
                              if(!in_array($donation_list->donation->donor, $donors)){
                                   array_push($donors, new UserResource($donation_list->donation->donor));
                              } 
                         }
                    } 
               } 
               return $donors;
```

Since Belongs To Many Through does not exist, I had to create a custom laravel relationship where I can get All Donors of an Agency. Now, I have 2 Questions.

Is there a way for me to dynamically load the getDonors()?

```
//  I am aware that this is wrong, I'd just like to give context if it's possible to do something like this
'donors' => $this->whenLoaded("donors", $this->getDonors()),
```

Is there an elegant way for me to make a custom Belongs To Many Relationship? So that I could just simply do

```
'donors' => $this->whenLoaded("donors")
```

I am aware that third party packages exist for Belongs To Many Relationships, but I'd like to know which one of these are best in your opinions as I am afraid of using a potentially wrong package and end up screwing my system much more.

Thanks Laracasts!

Comment: Do you have any findings related with the question? @Ignis